# Why does Python docopt say "-c requires argument" here?

Tags: python, windows, docopt

Python docopt works OK for simple cases, but in this case it keeps saying `-c requires argument`, despite it *having* an argument.

Minimal code (Python 3.6):

```
'''Usage:
test_docopt.py x YYY ZZZ [-a AAA] [-b BBB] [-c CCC]

Options:
   -a AAA  description
   -b BBB  description
   -c CCC  description'''

from docopt import docopt

print(docopt(__doc__))
```

Result:

```
C:\>python3 test_docopt.py x foo bar -a alpha -b bravo -c charlie
-c requires argument
Usage:
    test_docopt.py x YYY ZZZ [-a AAA] [-b BBB] [-c CCC]

C:\>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can't reproduce on windows or linux for me

Comment: Can you confirm that there's nothing weird happening in the shell and that all arguments are inf fact passed in. Try just putting `import sys; print(sys.argv)` in the script file.

Comment: @HåkenLid Thanks; that was it! (long story...but without your hint I wouldn't have puzzled it out).

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce in Linux:

```
$ python3 test_docopt.py x foo bar -a alpha -b bravo -c charlie
{'-a': 'alpha',
 '-b': 'bravo',
 '-c': 'charlie',
 'YYY': 'foo',
 'ZZZ': 'bar',
 'x': True}
```

either way I recommend using python's standard [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Comment: Well that's annoying.